# Javascript unshift(), recursion and making an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

```
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const arr = countdown(n - 1);
    arr.unshift(n);
    return arr;
  }
}
```

I found the above code in freeCodeCamp.  I ran it on VS code.  It works, but I don't understand how.  Here is my question:  How can you `unshift()` onto a variable that has not yet been declared as an array such as `[]`? It just says that `const arr = countdown(n-1)`. It does not say that `const arr` is an array such as "`[]`".  If I try to `unshift()` integers onto a variable that has been declared as just "`arr`" without any "`[]`", it runs as an error.  However, in this code that I found on freeCodeCamp, it works.  Why?

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Isn't there any explanation on FreeCodeCamp? Did you read?

Answer (score 3):

**substitution**

If I say `x = 5` and then ask *"What is `x + 3`?"*. Without much help one can answer, *8*. When you are asked *how* you arrived at your answer, you explain that you **substituted** `x` with its value, five, and then added plus three.

If given a function `f(x) = 3 * x + 2` or `max(a,b) = a > b ? a : b`, I can ask you other questions like what is `f(4)` or `max(9,7)`? And you'll arrive at the answer the same way:

- What is `f(4)`?

  - What is `f`? → `f` is `x -> 3 * x + 2`
  - What is `x`? →  `x` is `4`
  - What is `3 * 4 + 2`?

    - What is `3 * 4`? → The answer is `12`
    - What is `12 + 2`? → The answer is `14`
    - The answer is `14`
  - The answer is `14`
- The answer is `14`

---

- What is `max(9,7)`?

  - What is `max`? → `max` is `(a,b) => a > b ? a : b`
  - What are `a` and `b`? → `a` is `9` and `b` is `7`
  - What is `9 > 7 ? 9 : 7`?

    - What is `9 > 7`? → The answer is `true`
    - What is `true ? 9 : 7`? → The answer is `9`
    - The answer is `9`
  - The answer is `9`
- The answer is `9`

---

And so with a recursive function, we can use substitution to answer these questions

- What is `countdown(5)`?

  - What is `countdown`?

    - `countdown` is

      ```
      function countdown(n) {
        if (n < 1) {
          return [];
        } else {
          const arr = countdown(n - 1);
          arr.unshift(n);
          return arr;
        }
      }
      ```
  - What is `n`? → `n` is `5`
  - What is ...?

    ```
    if (5 < 1) {
      return [];
    } else {
      const arr = countdown(5 - 1);
      arr.unshift(5);
      return arr;
    }
    ```

    - What is `5 < 1`. → The answer is `false`
    - What is ...?

      ```
      if (false) {
        return [];
      } else {
        const arr = countdown(5 - 1);
        arr.unshift(5);
        return arr;
      }
      ```

      - The answer is

        ```
        const arr = countdown(5 - 1);
        arr.unshift(5);
        return arr;
        ```
      - What is `arr`?

        - The answer is `countdown(5 - 1)`
        - What is `5 - 1`? → The answer is `4`
        - **What is `countdown(4)`?**

---

**so what is `arr`**?

Using substitution to compute `countdown(5)` leads us to compute `countdown(4)`, where again we can use substitution. `countdown(4)` will look almost exactly the same as before, and as you continue on with `countdown(3)` and `countdown(2)` we notice the `n - 1` pattern play out. Until finally `n = 0` and the conditional `n < 1` is now `true`...

- What is `countdown(0)`?

  - The answer is `[]`

We can use substitution all the way -

- What is `countdown(3)`?

  - What is `arr`?
  - `arr` is `countdown(3 - 1)`
  - What is `countdown(2)`?

    - What is `arr`?
    - `arr` is `countdown(2 - 1)`
    - What is `countdown(1)`?

      - What is `arr`?
      - `arr` is `countdown(1 - 1)`
      - What is `countdown(0)`?

        - The answer is `[]`
      - `arr` is `[]`
      - What is `arr.unshift(1)`? → * The answer is `[1]`
      - The answer is `[1]`
    - `arr` is `[1]`
    - What is `arr.unshift(2)`? → The answer is `[2,1]`
    - The answer is `[2,1]`
  - `arr` is `[2,1]`
  - What is `arr.unshift(3)`? → The answer is `[3,2,1]`
  - The answer is `[3,2,1]`
- The answer is `[3,2,1]`

---

**one caveat**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional discipline yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignment, and other side effects. Above we can use substitution because `countdown` has [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). That's a fancy way to say that the function always returns the same result if the same inputs were given. In functional discipline you always design functions in this way, so your programs can be assembled and combined, like formulas in an evolving system of equations.

**there is no `arr`**

JavaScript has strong support for functional style and so our programs can be written with rich expressions. Program semantics are undisturbed by intermediate assignments like `arr` and syntax boilerplate like `if`, `else`, `return`, and `{...}` lying about.

```js
const countdown = n =>
  n < 1
    ? []
    : [ n, ...countdown(n - 1) ]
    
console.log(countdown(5))
```

```js
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: A *fantastic* answer.  Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: Ok.  So the answer comes out as [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ].  Is this because the answers to countdown(n-1) are put on  a stack and then unshift()..ed....onto the array with the last thing put on the stack "unshift"..ed first and the first thing put on the stack "unshift"...ed last?

Comment: understanding this in terms of a "stack" or `unshift` won't help much. as you can see, we implemented `countdown` without use of `unshift` or intermediate variables like `arr` and behaviour is identical. how would you explain your understanding in this situation? hint: the "answers to countdown(n - 1)" are always array.

Answer (score 1):

According to its definition, the function `countdown` satisfies the equations

```
.....
countdown(-2) = []
countdown(-1) = []
countdown(0) = []
countdown(1) = { const arr = countdown(0);
                 arr.unshift(1);
                 return arr;  }
             = countdown(0).unshift(1);        // countdown(0)=[]
             = [].unshift(1);
             = [1]
countdown(2) = countdown(1).unshift(2);        // countdown(1)=[1]
             = [1].unshift(2);
             = [2,1]
countdown(3) = countdown(2).unshift(3);        // countdown(2)=[2,1]
             = [2,1].unshift(3);
             = [3,2,1]
.....
```

so actually everything is defined quite alright.

Answer (score 0):

This works because `arr` is actually declared as an array. This is because when arr is declared it is declared as the output of `countdown(n -1)`. Since `countdown` has an exit condition that returns a new array `[]` which will eventually be reached because `n` is decreasing every time its called. This is a basic example of recursion, a goog way to find out how it works is to step through the code in you mind or a debugger.

Comment: so, "countdown (n-1)" in "arr = countdown(n-1)", actually returns as an array, so "arr" is an array?

Comment: Yes, eventually it will return an array so in this case `arr` is an array.